# Get value from each *ngFor ionic 4, ionic 5, ionic 6

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the following code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let box of boxes">
```

This will show results from array:
[image]

On the .ts file i have the following:

```
  isApproved : boolean;
  public box: any;
```

This will generate from boxes array:

- box1 -> [id, name, isApproved]
- box2 -> [id, name, isApproved]
- box3 ->[id, name, isApproved]

I need to get the isApproved value of each box, so when i activate the toggle, isApproved will change in database.

[image]

I know one method that doesn't fits my needs, like clicking and getting the id from route but i want to open a new page for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple.
The working code is:

On my HTML:

```
    <div *ngFor="let box of boxes"> 

        <ion-item-sliding id="anyId">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
              <img [offset]="100" [alt]="box.user?.name"
                defaultImage="./assets/img/photo.png" [lazyLoad]="box.user?.photo?.url()" />
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">

              <ion-text color="dark">
                <h3 class="bold no-margin">
                  {{ box.user?.name }}
                </h3>
              </ion-text>
            </ion-label>
           
          </ion-item>
      
          <ion-item-options side="end">
            <ion-item-option color="primary" (click)="onDelete(box)">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
            </ion-item-option>
          </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
    </div>
```

On my TS i have:

Importing service:

```
import { Box } from '../../services/box-service';
```

Before constructor:

```
  public boxes: Box[] = [];
  public box: Box;

constructor(private BoxService: Box) {
    super(injector);
  }
```

Loading boxes from service:

```
  async loadDataFromService() {
    try {

      const boxes = await this.boxService.loadBoxes(this.params);
      for (let box of boxes) {
        this.boxes.push(box);
      }
      
      this.onRefreshComplete(boxes);

    } catch {
    }
  }
```

... this will return an array with arrays. Each array has an object.

Now we just access each box from HTML **(click)="onDelete(box)"**

```
  async onDelete(box: Box) {

      await Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'Blah, blah',
        icon: 'warning',
        iconColor: '#5038de',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#5038de',
        cancelButtonColor: '#e0b500',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        heightAuto: false,
        showClass: {
          popup: 'animated fade-in'
        },
        hideClass: {
          popup: 'animated fade-out'
        }
      }).then(async (result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          await this.boxService.deleteBox(box)
          this.goTo()
        } else {
          this.goTo()
        }
      });

    }
  }
```

Resuming, the solution for:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let box of boxes">
  <ion-avatar slot="start"></ion-avatar>
  <ion-label>...</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle (ionChange)="myFunction(box)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

was simply **(ionChange)="myFunction(box)"** or **(click)="myFunction(box)**"

In my case **box** will be an entire object, passing the **id** will be enough to perform any action.

Answer (score 0):

Just put and `ngModel` in the `ion-toggle`:

`html:`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let box of boxes">
  <ion-avatar slot="start"></ion-avatar>
  <ion-label>...</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="box.isApproved" (ionChange)="approvedToggled($event)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

`ts:`

```
approvedToggled(event, box) {
   if(event.detail.value) {
      // save to box to database
   }
   /* or:
   if(item.isApproved) {
     // save to database
   }
   */
}
```

Comment: Hello, TypeError: Cannot set property isApproved of [object Object] which has only a getter at...

Comment: That's weird. Probaly this error is being thrown someplace else because theoretically we're not initially setting the value so the error should be something like `Cannot read property...`. Can you please show how you're populating the `boxes` array?